# What's the difference between <Component /> and Component()?

Tags: reactjs

I recently started to use the JSX element syntax instead of calling the function, because it makes the code prettier. But it looks like it's not the same. Suprising, because at `App.js`, function call causes infinite loop (and throws error), but JSX element works. At `Dashboard.js`, function call works perfectly, JSX element causes infinite loop (but doesn't throws error):

```
//App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState, memo } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUser } from "../firebase/user";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import SignIn from "./SignIn";
import "../styles/Global.scss";
import "../styles/App.scss";

const AppComponent = ({ userId, getUser }) => {

    useEffect(() => { getUser() }, []);

    const [ content, setContent ] = useState("");

    const Content = () => {
        if (userId === undefined) {
            return null;
        }
        if (userId) {
            setContent("dashboard");

            return <Dashboard />;
        } else {
            setContent("sign-in");

            return <SignIn />;
        }
    };
    return (
        <div className={`content-wrapper ${content}`}>
            <Content /> //works fine
            {Content()} //throws error
        </div>
    )
};

const App = memo(AppComponent);

const mapStateToProps = ({
    user: { userId }
}) => ({
    userId
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getUser
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

//Dashboard.js

import React, { useEffect, memo } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUserData } from "../firebase/user";
import { selectProject } from "../actions/projects";
import { getItem } from "../tools/LocalStorage";
import { getProjectDetails } from "../firebase/projects";
import { selectPages } from "../actions/pages";
import { getPagesDetails } from "../firebase/pages";
import Pages from "./Pages";
import Projects from "./Projects";
import Artboard from "./Artboard";

import "../styles/Dashboard.scss";

const cachedProject = JSON.parse(getItem("selectedProject"));
const cachedPages = JSON.parse(getItem("selectedPages"));

const DashboardComponent = ({
    userId,
    clientId,

    getUserData,

    selectedProject = cachedProject,
    selectedPages = cachedPages,
    pagesWithDetails,

    selectProject,
    selectPages,

    getProjectDetails,
    getPagesDetails
}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserData(userId);

        cachedProject && selectProject(cachedProject);
        cachedPages && selectPages(cachedPages);
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedProject && clientId) {
            getProjectDetails(
                clientId,
                selectedProject
            );
        }
    }, [selectedProject, clientId]);


    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedPages && selectedProject && clientId) {

            const withoutDetails = selectedPages.filter(pageId => (
                !pagesWithDetails.includes(pageId)
            ));

            getPagesDetails(
                selectedProject,
                withoutDetails
            );
        }
    }, [selectedPages, selectedProject, clientId]);


    const Content = () => {
        if (!clientId) return null;

        if (!selectedProject) {
            return <Projects />;
        }

        if (!selectedPages) {
            return <Pages />;
        }

        return <Artboard />;
    };

    return Content(); //worked good
    return <Content /> //caused infinite loop
};

const Dashboard = memo(DashboardComponent);

const mapStateToProps = ({
    user: {
        userId,
        clientId
    },
    projects: {
        selectedProject
    },
    pages: {
        selectedPages,
        pagesDetails
    }
}) => ({
    userId,
    clientId,

    selectedProject,
    selectedPages,

    pagesWithDetails: Object.keys(pagesDetails)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getUserData,

    selectProject,
    selectPages,

    getPagesDetails,
    getProjectDetails
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

I think it's an important information that the wrapper component is a function as well wrapped with `memo()`, but I still don't understand why the above happened. What's the working behind the two syntaxes, and why they are different?

Comment: What is the stack trace for the infinite loop, it should tell you which  component/function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Content()` is a regular function invokation, but `<Content />` is a `React.createElement` call.](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MIewdgLgppAUCUBuAUAHlJGEAEB6AfEA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.3&externalPlugins=)

**Input**

```
Content();
<Content />;
```

**Output**

```
Content();
React.createElement(Content, null);
```

Comment: Any idea why the difference causes infinite loop at `React.createElement` but not at function invocation?

Comment: @GergőHorváth Hard to say exactly what causes the infinite loop in your case, but you should not create a new component inside the render method of another component.

Comment: Suprising, but in an another case, according to your advice, I changed JSX syntax to function call, and it throws error: `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Comment: I expanded my snippet with the full component files