# Why do (some) CSS styles break when I defined a React functional component inside another functional component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tsx

Why does defining a React functional component inside another functional component break CSS transitions?

```
function Doohick({isOpen}: {isOpen: boolean}) {
    const style = {
        transition: 'opacity 2s ease',
        ...(isOpen ? {opacity: 1} : {opacity: 0})
    }

    return (
        <div style={style}>
            Doohick!!!
        </div>
    )
}

function Parent() {
   const [open, isOpen] = useState(false)
   return (
     <>
        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>Toggle Doohick</button>
        <Doohick isOpen={isOpen} />
     </>
   )
}
```

If I define `Doohick` outside of `Parent`, as above, everything works great. If I move the definition inside `Parent`, with no other changes, my CSS transitions break. Other CSS properties are fine.

**Why does defining a functional component inside another functional component break CSS transitions?**

### Complicated Explanation of Why I Want To Do This

I hear you asking: why would I want to do that? I'll tell you, but bear in mind you don't need to know any of this to understand the specific problem.

I want to encapsulate the `Doohick` state in a custom hook:

```
function useDoohick() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  
  const ToggleButton = 
    <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>Toggle Doohick</Button>
  
  const Doohick = <MyDoohick show={isOpen}/>

  return {ToggleButton, Doohick} 
}

function Parent() {
  const {Doohick, ToggleButton} = useDoohick()

  return (
    <>
      {ToggleButton}
      {Doohick}
    </>
  )
}
```

But I also want the `Parent` to be able to pass its own props into `Doohick` or `ToggleButton`. I can *almost* achieve that that like this:

```
function useDoohick() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  
  const ToggleButton = ({text}) =>
    <Button 
      onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
    >
     {text}
    </Button>
  
  const Doohick = () => 
    <MyDoohick show={isOpen} />

  return {ToggleButton, Doohick} 
}

function Parent() {
  return (
    <>
      <ToggleButton text='Burninate' />
      <Doohick />
    </>
  )
}
```

This works as advertised: `ToggleButton` renders with the expected label and controls whether or not `Doohick` is shown. But this pattern breaks some CSS styles (specifically, transitions) I have defined on `Doohick`. Other styles are fine.

I can still call it like this:

```
function Parent() {
  return (
    <>
      {ToggleButton({text: 'Burninate'})}
      {Doohick()}
    </>
  )
}
```

...and the transitions work correctly. But I would much prefer the standard JSX syntax here:

```
<ToggleButton text='Burninate />
```

Clearly, [`<Doohick />` and `Doohick()` are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725666/whats-the-difference-between-component-and-component). But what is it about the former that breaks CSS transitions here?

The root of the problem boils down to defining the custom components inside the `Parent`. The hook itself is irrelevant. But this pattern of encapsulating state in a custom hook while returning a customizable component is really powerful and *almost* works, so I'm hoping there's a way it can be saved.

### TL;DR

Why does defining a component within another component break my CSS transitions (and possibly other styles I haven't found yet)? How can I get around this while still calling my nested component with JSX-style syntax?

Answer (score 5):

Defining a component inside another component will always result in issues like this. Every time the outer component renders, you create a brand new definition of the inner component. It may have the same text as the one from the previous render, but it's a different function in memory, so as far as react can tell it's a different type of component.

The component type is the main thing that react looks for when [reconciling changes](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). Since the type changed, react is forced to unmount the old component and then mount the new one. So rather than having a `<div>` on the page who's style is changing, you have a div with some style, then it gets deleted and an unrelated div gets put onto the page. It may have a different style, but since this is a brand new div, the transition property won't do anything.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However: why does it work correctly when I defined `Doohick` inside `Parent` but call it like `{Doohick({isOpen})}`? I would think the same logic applies: `Doohick` should be re-created on every render and lose its (implicit) state.

Comment: If you're calling Doohick as a function, then you're executing its code immediately, and the thing you're returning from Parent is `<div>`'s and whatnot. React has no idea that Doohick even exists. When react does reconciliation, it's comparing div's with divs, not Doohick's with Doohicks, and all divs are the same type.

Comment: All such problems are resolvable with sufficient usememo.

See: https://blog.bitsrc.io/new-react-design-pattern-return-component-from-hooks-79215c3eac00